# Configuration data in database or in file

Tags: configuration

I found information about this already, but of more general kind and focused on "if the data shuld change a lot...". I will try to be one step more specific here.

I am developing a web application. It's possible to configure what should be presented or not. E.g. In a form, there can be a number of different drop-down lists, but it should be configured which drop-down lists should be presented.

Hence, it's going to be a lot of reading of the config info. Updating the configuration will be done very seldom. Also, the configuration itself should be performed with using a web application as well.

What's the best strategy, using files or database for the config data?

Comment: What framework/language is this being created in?

Comment: LAMP (PHP, Apache, MySQL, Linux).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Up until I read the requirement of

`the configuration itself should be performed with using a web application`,

I'd have said a flat file or PHP include would have sufficed, but given that requirement (and the availability of MySQL), I'd say use a database.

Plus, you never know when the config's update frequency will increase.

Answer (score 2):

I guess this depends on if you are already using a database for the rest of the web application. If you are then it makes sense to just add another table. Otherwise the overhead of setting up a database server and managing connections just for configuration is too much. In which case a flat file using structured text is probably your best bet.

If you are already using a database, you could cache the results so that the overhead of looking up the results is lower, then clear the cache when the config is updated.

Comment: I'm using a database already. But it's new development so how I should do the configuration is still open. The only configuration I've done so far I did put in a file, it made sence and is not data related to my question above.

Answer (score 2):

The best strategy is encapsulation.

If you encapsulate access to your configuration data properly, you'll be able to start off with whichever implementation meets your short term requirements, safe in the knowledge that you can change it later.

Comment: Thanks! That's something I always do.